# Trying to Pull Long String From Cell in Worksheet for Query to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I have some sample code that works fire for a smll SQL string, but for a large string, with almos 2500 characters in length, it gives me the following error.

[image]

```
Sub ADOExcelSQLServer()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Server_Name As String
    Dim Database_Name As String
    Dim User_ID As String
    Dim Password As String
    Dim SQLStr As String
    Dim mysql As String * 2500
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
     
    Server_Name = "my_server_name" ' Enter your server name here
    Database_Name = "my_db_name" ' Enter your database name here
    User_ID = "" ' enter your user ID here
    Password = "" ' Enter your password here
    mysql = Worksheets("SQL").Range("A2").Text
    Debug.Print mysql
    
    SQLStr = mysql
     
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Cn.Open "Driver={SQL Server};Server=" & Server_Name & ";Database=" & Database_Name & _
    ";Uid=" & User_ID & ";Pwd=" & Password & ";"
     
    rs.Open SQLStr, Cn, adOpenStatic
     ' Dump to spreadsheet
    For iCols = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        Worksheets("DataDump").Cells(1, iCols + 1).Value = rs.Fields(iCols).Name
    Next
    With Worksheets("DataDump").Range("A1:ZZ500000") ' Enter your sheet name and range here
        '.ClearContents
        .CopyFromRecordset rs
    End With
     '            Tidy up
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Cn.Close
    Set Cn = Nothing
End Sub
```

The Debug.Print prints everything to the Immediate Window just fine, when I get to this line: `rs.Open` I see the error message popup. If a cell can handle 32767 characters, there must be a way to get more than 128 characters in a SQL clause, right!

Comment: Something is wrong in your SQL, but we can't see it, so it's difficult to say what needs to be fixed. 2500 characters should not be a problem. Try removing that comment (and any others).  See for example https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/169911/Avoid-single-line-comments-in-query-to-OLE-DB-Data (that's for Oracle but may be the same issue here)

Comment: [ADODB.RecordSet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/recordset-object-ado)s are meant to open views and tables directly, or return the result set from [ADODB.Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/command-object-parameters)s. If you want to execute statements directly using an `ADODB.RecordSet` object have you considered supplying the [`adCmdText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/guide/data/creating-and-executing-a-simple-command?view=sql-server-ver16#using-a-recordset-object) Option value to enable that behavior?

Comment: I removed the -- characters (SQL comments) comments and I noticed the " characters at the beginning and end, so I removed those too, and now it works. Thanks everyone!!